# Increase font-size for small screens but not phones?

Tags: responsive-design

Iv noticed that around 680px the text on http://www.smashingmagazine.com/ increases in size.  This is done with a media query setting the body font-size: 1.1875em. However when you get down to a smaller size like you would be on a phone then the text becomes the normal size again.

Why would they do this? I thought that one of the concepts of responsive design was to give control to the device / user. So if the body text is best at 1em then you simply let the device use its default to determine what size the text will be. But it seems they have decided to override this device default.

Answer (score 0):

```
Just give size with sp example 12sp. it will take size for all resolution..
```

Comment: I havnt heard of sp for font sizes before so im guessing the support isnt the best?

Comment: i did used it so many universal apps..it is too best....u can try it..i hope it will work with you....other wise can you tell me exact problem which u got..i will try to solve it.